# How can use elements "getElementById("site") and getElementById("button")" more than one for lists?

Tags: javascript, html, list

I tried to use **more than one "List"** with changing names of **getElementById("site")** and **getElementById("button")** but it dosent work well.

The "submit" button dosnt work correctly
I want each button do **separately** and open link from own list.

This example for 3 list, but I have more than 10 lists with same name but different addresses.

**HTML code:**

```
<html>

<body>
    <form method="get">
        <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
        <select id="site01" name="site">
            <option value="Google">Google</option>
            <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
            <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="button01">Submit</button>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <form method="get">
        <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
        <select id="site02" name="site">
            <option value="Google">Google</option>
            <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
            <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="button02">Submit</button>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <form method="get">
        <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
        <select id="site03" name="site">
            <option value="Google">Google</option>
            <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
            <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="button03">Submit</button>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script1.js code**

```
var select = document.getElementById('site01');

document.getElementById("button01").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    if (value == "Google")
    {
        window.open('https://www.google01.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "Yahoo")
    {
        window.open('https://www.yahoo01.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "MSN")
    {
        window.open('https://www.msn01.com', '_blank');
    }
};

var select = document.getElementById('site02');

document.getElementById("button02").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    if (value == "Google")
    {
        window.open('https://www.google02.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "Yahoo")
    {
        window.open('https://www.yahoo02.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "MSN")
    {
        window.open('https://www.msn02.com', '_blank');
    }
};

var select = document.getElementById('site03');

document.getElementById("button03").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    if (value == "Google")
    {
        window.open('https://www.google03.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "Yahoo")
    {
        window.open('https://www.yahoo03.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "MSN")
    {
        window.open('https://www.msn03.com', '_blank');
    }
};
```

whats wrong ?

Comment: The "submit" button dosnt work correctly :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that, you are keep on updating value for select as

```
var select = document.getElementById('site01'); // First
var select = document.getElementById('site02'); // Second
var select = document.getElementById('site03'); // Third
```

Your select variable is declared in global scope, so updating one value will reflect all elements.

**Fix to your issue**

Move the declaration of `select` inside the the click listner. This will be redeclared each tim when user clicks the button and hence, the value will be taken correctly.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
document.getElementById("button01").onclick = function () {
  const select = document.getElementById('site01');
  const value = select.value
  if (value == "Google") {
    window.open('https://www.google01.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "Yahoo") {
    window.open('https://www.yahoo01.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "MSN") {
    window.open('https://www.msn01.com', '_blank');
  }
};

document.getElementById("button02").onclick = function () {
  const select = document.getElementById('site02');
  const value = select.value
  if (value == "Google") {
    window.open('https://www.google02.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "Yahoo") {
    window.open('https://www.yahoo02.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "MSN") {
    window.open('https://www.msn02.com', '_blank');
  }
};

document.getElementById("button03").onclick = function () {
  const select = document.getElementById('site03');
  const value = select.value
  if (value == "Google") {
    window.open('https://www.google03.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "Yahoo") {
    window.open('https://www.yahoo03.com', '_blank');
  }
  else if (value == "MSN") {
    window.open('https://www.msn03.com', '_blank');
  }
};
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site01" name="site" data-node="01">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button01">Submit</button>
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site02" name="site" data-node="02">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button02">Submit</button>
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site03" name="site" data-node="03">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button03">Submit</button>
```

What happens with this is, the value for select will be holding the last node finally, that is the element with id `site03`. So your select will be holding the value of the third node always. So even if you click the first button or the second button, it will take the value from the third node.

Also donot call `<script src="script1.js"></script>` multiple time from template. This should be done only once, best to keep at the bottom of your template section.

**Better Approach**

Better approach is to, select all your buttons using `document.querySelectorAll("[type='button']")` and add a click event listner to that. Inside the click event listner, select the targeted select node by accessing the select using `e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.querySelector('select')`. You can see the code comment how this selector will point to the required target.

To make the urls dyynamic, you can have some custom data attributes in the select element and check the value for the corresponding data attributes inside the change event. I have added a custom `data-node` to each select and fetched the value from the change event using `select.getAttribute('data-node')`

**Working Code**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[type='button']").forEach((node) => {
  node.onclick = function (e) {
    const select = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.querySelector('select');
    // e.currentTarget => clicked button
    // e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling = Form ust above the button
    // e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.querySelector('select') = Select inside the form
    const value = select.value
    const nodeAppender = select.getAttribute('data-node');
    console.log(value);
    if (value == "Google") {
      window.open(`https://www.google${nodeAppender}.com`, '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "Yahoo") {
      window.open(`https://www.yahoo${nodeAppender}.com`, '_blank');
    }
    else if (value == "MSN") {
      window.open(`https://www.msn${nodeAppender}.com`, '_blank');
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site01" name="site" data-node="01">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button01">Submit</button>
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site02" name="site" data-node="02">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button02">Submit</button>
<form method="get">
  <label for="Links">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site03" name="site" data-node="03">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button03">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. now I have question. we have 3 lists and for each list we have 3 different addresses, some time we have same **name** but different addresses. in your code all list going to one name and one address. how we can separate each list for own address?

Comment: To make the urls dyynamic, you can have some custom data attributes in the select element and check the value for the corresponding data attributes inside the change event. I have added a custom `data-node` to each select and fetched the value from the change event using `select.getAttribute('data-node')`

Comment: tnq, but I want to set unique address for name in each list. for example **list01** = `MainPage : www.pic.com` , **list02** = `MainPage : www.music.com` **list03** = `MainPage : www.Movie.com` as you see some time we have same name but different addresses. want every list goes to won code.

Comment: @Sina, the question is do you need 3 listner function for 3 buttons or handle the logic for 3 button click on a single function? Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Sina both implemetattions are possible. So which is the implementation u are looking for?

Comment: I need 3 listener function for 3 buttons (in my project I need more than 20 listener)

Comment: If that is the case, why cant you directly add an onclick event to your buttons?

Comment: because I dont want to use the addresses in the main code and want to recall from other place. if my problem solved by directly add an onclick event to buttons, can you do that for me?

Comment: @Sina updated the answer, please check

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I use it for 30 lists with different addresses, names and worked **perfectly**. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

When change select option, you didn't store **changed value** that's why always you show first loaded data that's why its not working exactly.

Please check following codes and run it in your environmnet.

```
var selectValue = document.getElementById('site01').value;

document.getElementById('site01').addEventListener('change', function() {
  selectValue = this.value;
});

document.getElementById("button01").onclick = function(){
    if (selectValue == "Google")
    {
        window.open('https://www.google01.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (selectValue == "Yahoo")
    {
        window.open('https://www.yahoo01.com', '_blank');
    }
    else if (selectValue == "MSN")
    {
        window.open('https://www.msn01.com', '_blank');
    }
};
```

Hopefully, now it'll be worked, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. with your help it worked much better. but it has a few bugs. for example if change first list and click on second button we have **"first element Id"** but open link from **"second address list"**. can do some thing for reset every list to select null when click on any **submit** button?

Comment: @Sina, I have just coded for only one, you can change all according to my codes, please.  you don't do this, let me know. I'll back to you later.

Comment: I used it for 3 list and test it. as I said, its work but has a few bugs. if you change any list and hit the button thats ok, but if change list **number one** and hit **number two** button not work correctly (because it not understand button one for list one and button two for list two) did you get it? please test it you will understand :) anyway thanks for your solution :)